# Setting php_value in VirtualHost on Debian Squeeze Apache 2.4.10 + mod_proxy_fcgi + php-fpm?

Tags: php, apache-2.4, php-fpm, debian-jessie, mod-proxy-fcgi

After updating our server to Debian Jessie (8.3), I switched Apache 2.4.10 from mpm_worker/mod_php to mpm_event/proxy_fcgi/php-fpm. I have the handoff configured for all virtual hosts as such:

```
# cat conf-enabled/php5-fpm.conf 
<FilesMatch \.php$>
    SetHandler "proxy:unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock|fcgi://localhost/"
</FilesMatch>
```

I have also disabled mod_php. Because of that, apache will not let me have  php_admin_value/php_value/php_flag directives in the VirtualHosts files.

```
Invalid command 'php_value', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
```

I've read a bit about .user.ini files, but it doesn't sound like the directives I need to set will are supported in there, and I just successfully removed all the .htaccess files from my site for performance reasons, so this seems like a backward (and incompatible) approach.

The other common suggestion is to make a unique pool for each VirtualHost, but this concerns me for two reasons:

1. Complexity of setup - right now, the configuration is super-simple
2. Switching from socket to TCP? Am I correct in that that I need a unique TCP port per pool? Would I alternatively need a unique socket per pool?
3. Memory allocation! This server doesn't have as much RAM as I'd like. It seems wasteful to have a bunch of php-fpm instances spun-up for the lesser-visited sites on the server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the end, I just defined some [HOST=] sections in my /etc/php5/fpm/php.ini configuration.

http://php.net/manual/en/ini.sections.php

This felt more secure than using mod_env or .user.ini.

Comment: This worked well for me and meant that I didn't have to spin up multiple pools just to segregate error logs. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: It's probably worth adding that these sections _must_ be in the standard config files (php.ini and conf.d/*) and not the _fpm_ config files (php-fpm.conf and pool.d/*). The _fpm_ config files are specifically for configuring pools so any [HOST=] sections will be creating a new pool not just adding some config.

Comment: can't get this to work. I'm trying to use a [PATH=...] section in my custom php.ini in conf.d. It is successfully being parsed but settings are not activated when using [PATH=...]. Any idea on this?

Answer (score 4):

You can pass environment variables to the CGI pool from Apache configuration files:

```
    SetEnv PHP_ADMIN_VALUE "open_basedir=/path-to-your-doc-root"
    <FilesMatch \.php$>
        SetHandler "proxy:unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock|fcgi://localhost/"
    </FilesMatch>
```

`mod_env` must be enabled, and you must disable `.htaccess` file handling, if third party users can upload, or modify them (`AllowOverride None`). If you need to pass more than one variable, you must concatenate them with a newline char (`\n`).

A malicious user can change `open_basedir` or other important PHP configuration variables (ie.: `disable_functions`) with a simple `.htaccess`. I don't know if it's possible to prevent this behavior.

Reference: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=51595